How can I fix the error using Java, Spring, Gemini AI, Google Cloud Vertex AI: Your default credentials were not found?
I have created a small test project using Java and Spring Boot to integrate with Google Gemini AI.
For this I added dependency to google-cloud-vertexai library to my pom.xml:
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>26.49.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-vertexai</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

After that I added such simple controller:
package com.example.testing.controller;

import com.google.cloud.vertexai.VertexAI;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.GenerateContentResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.PredictionServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.GenerativeModel;
import com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.ResponseHandler;
import java.io.IOException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

  private final PredictionServiceClient predictionServiceClient;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam String textPrompt) {
    String projectId = "vertex-ai-java-api-for-gemini";
    String location = "us-central1";
    String modelName = "gemini-1.5-flash-001";

    String output = textInput(projectId, location, modelName, textPrompt);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(output);
  }

  public String textInput(String projectId, String location, String modelName, String textPrompt) {
    try (VertexAI vertexAI = new VertexAI(projectId, location)) {
      GenerativeModel model = new GenerativeModel(modelName, vertexAI);
      GenerateContentResponse response = model.generateContent(textPrompt);
      return ResponseHandler.getText(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      String errorMessage = "Error occurred: " + e.getMessage();
      log.error(errorMessage, e);
      throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
    }
  }
}


When I run my app I got the next error:
2024-11-01T08:49:51.542+02:00 ERROR 10824 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.] with root cause

java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:127) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.28.0.jar:1.28.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:152) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.28.0.jar:1.28.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:124) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.28.0.jar:1.28.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:70) ~[gax-2.55.0.jar:2.55.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.getCredentials(ClientContext.java:290) ~[gax-2.55.0.jar:2.55.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:181) ~[gax-2.55.0.jar:2.55.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.stub.GrpcPredictionServiceStub.create(GrpcPredictionServiceStub.java:295) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.stub.PredictionServiceStubSettings.createStub(PredictionServiceStubSettings.java:323) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.PredictionServiceClient.<init>(PredictionServiceClient.java:427) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.api.PredictionServiceClient.create(PredictionServiceClient.java:409) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.VertexAI.newPredictionServiceClient(VertexAI.java:345) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:200) ~[guava-33.3.1-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.VertexAI.getPredictionServiceClient(VertexAI.java:334) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.GenerativeModel.generateContent(GenerativeModel.java:467) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.GenerativeModel.generateContent(GenerativeModel.java:454) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.GenerativeModel.generateContent(GenerativeModel.java:441) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.google.cloud.vertexai.generativeai.GenerativeModel.generateContent(GenerativeModel.java:429) ~[google-cloud-vertexai-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.example.testing.controller.TestController.textInput(TestController.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.testing.controller.TestController.test(TestController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.11.jar:10.1.11]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]


Then I added env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with path to JSON-file with key from my Google service accout and it started working well, but what if I would like to transfer this integration to DEV env or PROD env, where I can face with DevOps issue because of JSON-file location and env var. Is there any way to avoid JSON-file and env var using and to set credentials programmatically, for instance like I set programatically projectId or region location in my code example?
If you know a way to use Gemini AI from the Java app and avoid authentication it will be also very helpful knowledge.
Thank you in advance!

The current recommended way to authenticate your applications hosted in prod environments is Workload Identity Pools
Also, you can deploy your app to App Engine, which has it's own service account whose permissions can be tailored. These credentials are automatically injected as application-default credentials.
Another way (not recommended) is to host a SA key in your deployment environment, which would likely point to a similar credentials file.
